# Firebase cloud messaging HTTP v1 messages:send endpoint timeouts

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We're using the following fcm http v1 endpoint to dispatch push notifications:
`https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project}/messages:send`

### The problem:

is that the endpoint is super **slow**, and sometimes it takes more than 5 seconds to get a response.
As a result **our requests fail**. This happens VERY often (Multiple times per day. The payloads are small - 0.5kb)

### My question

Should I consider that normal and increase the timeout to something like 10 seconds, or should I be worried about some bigger issue?

Has anyone else noticed that issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you have concerns about the performance of some Firebase API that's not addressed in the documentation, you should take that up with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).